# Am I over watering my sedums?

Tags: sedum

They look like these .., they all grew tall and flowered... it looks nice in the beginning but then they seem to over grow and they start leaning in different directions and then it does not look compact and neat anymore

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are they full sun? How much you "over" water? Are you sure that your Sedum is a small size one?

Comment: yes full sun, watering them every other day. I have 4-5 varieties and they are all overgrown ...they were much smaller in the first year.